# Evaluating a tensor potential of the type $\hat{\mathbf{S}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I am trying to reproduce a result I found in an article. Basically a part of a two-body potential is written in the form
$$V_T(r) = V_t(r)\left( 6 \frac{\hat{\mathbf{S}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}-2\,\hat{\mathbf{S}}^2\right)$$
I am trying to reproduce the value the angular part of the potential acting on states of the kind
$$S_{12}\equiv\bigg\langle J(\ell'S)\mu'\bigg|\,6 \frac{\hat{\mathbf{S}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}-2\,\hat{\mathbf{S}}^2\,\bigg|J(\ell S)\mu\bigg\rangle$$
In the case $S=1$ it should give
$$\langle J(\ell'S)\mu'|V_T(r)|J(\ell S)\mu\rangle = -\frac{2(J-1)}{2J+1}\qquad 
\mathrm{for}\qquad \ell'=\ell=J-1$$
$$\langle J(\ell'S)\mu'|V_T(r)|J(\ell S)\mu\rangle = 6\frac{\sqrt{J(J+1)}}{2J+1}\qquad \mathrm{for}\qquad \ell'=J+1\mathrm{~and~}\ell=J-1\quad\mathrm{or}\quad \ell'=J-1\mathrm{~and~}\ell=J+1$$
$$\langle J(\ell'S)\mu'|V_T(r)|J(\ell S)\mu\rangle = -\frac{2(J+2)}{2J+1}\qquad 
\mathrm{for}\qquad \ell'=\ell=J+1$$

What I have been able to prove so far is
$$S_{12}=\delta_{\mu'\mu}\,(-)^{J+\ell-\ell'+S}\,36\,
 \sqrt{(2\ell+1)(2\ell'+1)}
 \sum_{L=0}^2
 (-)^L
 \left\{
 \begin{matrix}
 \ell' & \ell & L\\
 S & S & J
 \end{matrix}
 \right\}
 \left\{
 \begin{matrix}
 S & S & L\\
 S & S & S
 \end{matrix}
 \right\}\\\times
 \langle{1\,0\,1\,0}|{L\,0}\rangle
 \langle{\ell\,0\,\ell'\,0}|{L\,0}\rangle - 2\, S(S+1)\delta_{\mu'\mu}$$
Is there any good soul which could help me through the remaining steps?